# Can I Use get and set on ActionListener? Why don't work?

Tags: java, concurrency, actionlistener

See below:

/*this is my main*/

```
package br.com.general;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Wind w = new Wind();
        w.start();

        while(true){
            //System.out.printf("%b\n", w.button());
            if(w.button()){
                System.out.printf("xx %b\n", w.button());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

/*this is my JFrame Window with one button*/

```
package br.com.general;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Wind extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Act a = new Act();

    public Wind() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton B = new JButton("on");

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);  

        B.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 30);
        B.addActionListener(a);

        add(B);
        setSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void start() {
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public boolean button(){
        return(a.button());
    }
    public void buttonOk(){
        a.zero();
    }
}
```

/*and in the end this is my ActionListener for my button */

```
package br.com.general;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Act implements ActionListener {
    boolean s;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        s = true;

    }
    public boolean button(){
        return(s);
    }
    public void zero(){
        s = false;
    }
}
```

if you run, you can see that don't works, but if, in the main, you remove the "//" and enable the line "System.out.printf("%b\n", w.button());" it starts functioning....
WHY? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question! In an ideal world your code would run without issues, no matter if the first `System.out.println(…)` is commented out or not.

The problem is that Java optimizes your code and does *not* always retrieve the current value of your `s` flag in the `Act` class.

To circumvent this (in this case wrong) optimization, you can use the `volatile` modifier: `volatile boolean s;`. This requires the JVM to *always* retrieve the actual value from memory and prevents caching it, see [Atomic Access in *The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have hard infinite loop that consumes all the resources. You probably should insert small delay (ex, 10-100ms) into the loop. This can be done using Thread.wait() method. In your case delay is produced by System.out.printf(), since console output is quite slow.

Comment: I don't think that resource consumption is the problem here (although [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is indeed not good in most cases): Try to add something to the event handler method (e.g. `System.out.println("Button clicked");`) and you will see it gets executed without delay and the GUI is responsive.